# How to open "zxing Barcode" scanning screen in a small window?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

"zxing Barcode" scanner is successfully working in my App

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

I want to open the scanning screen (i.e., Intent), on same Activity in the center in a small window

How can I get this type of Interface ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpT5R.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [Journey's Library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded). You can use the scanner as a component just like an image or a text. It's based on ZXing. =)

Comment: Hey @KinSnowfox , This is what I am using, but I couldn't fin to use it as a Component. Right now I am using it as an Intent on a Button Click. But I want , not to use it as Intent rather, use it in same screen just as Displaying Textview or Imageview

Comment: Read the ContinuousCaptureActivity example. You will se an example just like you want. A few weeks ago I was looking for the same thing and that solved my problem almost like magic. =)

Comment: Hey @KinSnowfox , Thank You very much. This is what I was looking for ("ContinuousCaptureActivity.java"). Thank a Lot (Y)

Comment: Hey @KinSnowfox There's a new Issue I am having.  Right now I am using "Journey's Library" as it is without making any changes, and its working perfectly fine , I am loading a IntentIntegrator on a button click. What I need to do now is, When the Scanner opens with a red line in center, I do not want it to AutoDetect the Barcode, I want a small button at the bottom of screen or anywhere, and after placing the red line on a particular barcode (out of bunches of barcode near to each other), when we click on the bottom button it should detect the barcode and process it. Any Help ?

Comment: If you want to use a button to start scan just remove the `barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback)` and call `barcodeView.decodeSingle(callback)` inside an event, like `OnClickListener`, for example.