# Xamarin.Android : ZXing scanner from a small area (not fullscreen)

Tags: android, xamarin, barcode, zxing

I would like to display the scanner in a small area and not in full-screen, as in the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937104/how-to-open-zxing-barcode-scanning-screen-in-a-small-window) (but Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross in fragment).

For this, I've my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/barcodeview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0">
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#d13033"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</FrameLayout>
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_product"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Products" />
```

like as https://i.stack.imgur.com/nouxm.jpg

And my fragment view :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.Products, null);
    var activity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
    MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(activity.Application);
    var barcodeview = view.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.barcodeview);

    var scanner = new ZXingScannerFragment();
    scanner.UseCustomOverlayView = true;
    scanner.CustomOverlayView = barcodeview;
    scanner.StartScanning(result =>
    {
        Mvx.Trace("Scanned with ZXingScannerFragment : " + result.Text);
    });
    //_mobileBarcodeScanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
    //_mobileBarcodeScanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;
    //_mobileBarcodeScanner.CustomOverlay = barcodeview;
    //_mobileBarcodeScanner.Torch(true);
    //_mobileBarcodeScanner.ScanContinuously(result =>
    //{
    //    Mvx.Trace("Scanned :" + result.Text);
    //});
    return view;
}
```

}

I tried with MobileBarcodeScanner and ZXingScannerFragment classes :

With MobileBarcodeScanner, the scanner launches in full-screen and works.

With ZXingScannerFragment, the scanner does not start. Even if I use the `FragmentManager.Replace(barcodeview, new ZXingScannerFragment()).Commit())`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar to this but used a different approach. I integrated ZXing directly into my application. Then I used the class found here

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java

to model my class off of. The important code to modify is in the onResume and onPause method, something along the lines of

```
SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
if (hasSurface) {
    // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still exists. Therefore
    // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
    initCamera(surfaceHolder);
 } else {
        // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the camera.
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
}
```

where R.id.preview_view can be replaced with the small area view you want to use.

Comment: He is using `Zxing.Net.Mobile` not `zxing/zxing`